# Reparametrization of a circle

Tags: differential-geometry, parametrization

Let $\,\mathbf{x}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2\,$ and $\,\mathbf{y}:J\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2\;$ be two parametrizations of a circle, given by
$$\mathbf{x}\left(\theta\right)=\left(\cos\theta,\,\sin\theta\right)\qquad\mathbf{y}\left(t\right)=\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\,\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)$$
I am asked to find a relation between both parameters $\,\left(\right.$i.e a dipheomorphism $\,f:I\longrightarrow J\,$ that verifies $\,\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}\circ f\left.\right)$

---

After different attempts, I tried setting $\,\textrm{tg}\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\,$ and it seems to be a right change of variables. However, it was just luck.

**Question:** Is there a specific method for this kind of exercise?

Comment: Please specify the extremes of the intervals $ I $ and $ J $.

Comment: @MathOverview: They are not defined. I guess I=[0,2π) and J an interval which allows to draw the whole circle.